# How to authenticate with angularfire2 after I had authenticated with cordova-plugin-firebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, angularfire2

I had use Phone Authentication using cordova-plugin-firebase. now I want access firestore with angularfire2. Although I have authenticated with plugin it is not working with the angularfire2. Main problem is that there is auto verification in android which doesn't return the credentials from plugin. Therefore I cant use sign in with credentials in angularfire2.

I tried to get JWT token and sing in with custom token in angularfire2. But that doesn't work.